# Remote ssh server port 22 monitoring

Tags: ssh, monitoring, cdn, nagios, nrpe

We are having our windows servers in AWS, which have problems doing sshget from cdn server, we are getting timeouts and we dont know why.

Can we put a check in naemon(monitoring server) based on nagios so that the NRPE in servers executes a telnet to remote host johndoetv.upload.cdn.com at port 22 and gets critical after 30 seconds in case of connectivity.

I tried `check_tcp` but it's failing, or can i use nrpe in this case on remote server in windows

eg.

```
define service {
  service_description            akamai_sshget
  hostgroup_name                 playready
  use                            generic-service
  check_command                  check_tcp -H ctv.upload.akamai.com -p 22 -w 15 -c 30
  contact_groups                 admins
}
```

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: I don't know to be honest i am not a programmer, I only install nagios naemon version and modify existing templates to use for monitoring. Does anyone know how can i monitor connectivity from windows server towards cdn dns at port 22 over a period of week and generate reports in case of any downtime ?

Answer (score 0):

I've defined a command that ssh's into a box, then runs check_ssh (a standard nagios thing) against another server:

```
define command {
        command_name    ssh_check_ssh
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_by_ssh -H $_HOSTGATEWAY$ -C "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ssh $HOSTADDRESS$"
}
```

You'll need to define `_gateway` and `address` for the servers, and put in the address of the server you are having connection issues from:

```
define host{
  use                  generic-host
  host_name            ctv.upload.akamai.com
  alias                ctv.upload.akamai.com
  address              ctv.upload.akamai.com
  _gateway             server.that.is.having.connection.issus
  check_command        ssh_check_ssh
}
```

Obviously you can adapt that to make it work with groups rather than single hosts.

Comment: we have a a poershell script that is simulating sshget tasks, we would like to add this feature in nagios instead of depending upon powershell, so from our nagios server can we simulate a script towards cdn ?

Comment: i tried above but when i restarted naemon i get error message, which means syntax is incorrect, also we use /lib64 and not /lib

Comment: Are you able to run the command on its own, i.e. `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_by_ssh -H $_HOSTGATEWAY$ -C "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh $HOSTADDRESS$"`?  (obviously replacing the stuff surrounded by $$ appropriately?

Comment: Another option if all you really want is a log of success / failure would be to use a cronjob and a bash script.  Something like `nc -q 1 -w 1 ctv.upload.akamai.com 22` - the exit code would give you success failure, then you can write whatever you want to a log?